# Gnu Parallel with multiple arguments - selective command execution

Tags: linux, file, parallel-processing, gnu

I have a program that takes 3 arguments -t, -a and -s - for example,

```
./Run -t 1500 -a 150000 -s filename
```

This program will append data as a row (of 7 columns) to the end of the file "filename".

I want to study how these two parameters affect my output for ranges t in (1500,150000 [steps of 5000]) and a in (500,600000 [steps of 500]). As of now what I am doing is,

```
parallel -j+0 ./Run -t {2} -a {1} :::: <(seq 500 500 600000) :::: <seq(1500 5000 15000)
```

As can be seen the parameter t is swept through its range for each value of parameter a. This prints out all the data into the file, all right.

But for ease in use of the data I want it to add 2 blank lines to the file after each parameter a is completely evaluated so I can go ahead with my processing. This means that I should add

```
echo "" >> filename
```

each time the parameter a is updated.

How do i do this with gnu parallel?

Comment: "This program will append data as a row (of 7 columns) to the end of the file "filename"." What happens if 2 program append at exactly the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find appending to the same file in parallel scary: There are certain situations where it is safe to do, but there are sooo many situations where it is not safe:

```
# Generate files with a single very long line
parallel -j0 perl -e '\$a=\"1{}\"x10000000\;print\ \$a,\"\\n\"' '>' {} ::: {a..z}
rm -f out.par 
# Grep for the single line in parallel - append to same file
parallel -j0 'grep 1 >> out.par' ::: {a..z}
# This ought to only give a single line for each letter
# But because of race condition some lines are split into two
parallel --tag 'grep {} out.par | wc -l' ::: {a..z}
rm out.par
# Do the same in serial (no race condition)
parallel -j1 'grep 1 >> out.par' ::: {a..z}
# Only a single line per letter
parallel --tag 'grep {} out.par | wc -l' ::: {a..z}
# Do the same in parallel but with serialized output (no race condition)
parallel -j0 grep 1 ::: {a..z} > out.par
# Only a single line per letter
parallel --tag 'grep {} out.par | wc -l' ::: {a..z}
```

So if I were you I would first change `./Run` to output to stdout (standard output), so you can do:

```
./Run -t 1500 -2 500 > filename
# And in parallel:
parallel ./Run -t {2} -2 {1} :::: <(seq 500 500 600000) :::: <(seq 1500 5000 15000) > filename
```

To solve your original question we need to agree, that order does matter: It is unacceptable if the jobs are output in completely random order. Therefore we need `--keep-order` (-k).

```
parallel -k ./Run -t {2} -2 {1} :::: <(seq 500 500 600000) :::: <(seq 1500 5000 15000) > filename
```

Now we just need to make something that only runs if the first parameter is 11500:

```
parallel -k './Run -t {2} -2 {1}; if [ {2} -eq 11500 ]; then echo "";fi' :::: <(seq 500 500 600000) :::: <(seq 1500 5000 15000) > filename
```

I am not sure what you need it for, but you might want to take a look at `--tag` as that might be useful for you.